# Issue with namespaces and form names

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, namespaces

I have an issue that I don't know if it is part of C# or another kind...

I created a new project, in this project I made two folders one name `Products` and  `Clients`, inside the folder `Products` I created one form named `Products.cs` and inside `Clients` one named `Clients.cs`, I was working with the form `Products.cs` and added a button to open `Clients.cs` to open that form this is the code I use

```
Clients.Clients cli = new Clients.Clients();
cli.showDialog();
```

And all is working fine till now, but if I do the same process that I did before just changing the fact that I made the `Products.cs` and `Clients.cs` files before the folders and I wrote this code to open `Clients.cs` form

```
Clients cli = new Clients();
cli.showDialog();
```

then I made the folders with same name and I simply moved these `.cs` files inside their respective folder and still is working fine, why is not require the `Clients.Clients` part in this case? but if in the first case I remove that part C# says **Clients is namespace but is used like a type**

What does this means? sorry I'm new with C# and can't find an answer to this, I hope you can help me and explain it to me, thank you.

Comment: Did you look at the namespaces visual studio generated for you and how they compared between your attempts? That should clear things up a bit.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one/

Comment: I will check it again @BrootsWaymb and i will read that link

Comment: Placing a file inside a folder doesn't change it's Namespace. It just lets you organize things. Any file in your project that has the same namespace can be directly accessed.

Comment: You can always remove the *sub-namespace* added by VS from your classes. The Project's Namespace is modified for your convenience (it supposes that's what you want, since you asked for this, creating a different *organization*), but you don't need to accept it.